# How to assign random numbers to 2 variables, and then assign new random numbers to those 2 variables when needed?

Tags: java, arraylist, random

I need to write a program (using inheritance) that uses a random number generator to produce 2 random numbers, present the two numbers as an addition question, and then when the question is answered, produce a new question that uses new random numbers. So far, I have the following code in 3 separate java files:

```
public int numberGenerator()
   {
       int num = 0;
       Random ranNum = new Random();
       ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
       
       for (int i = 1; i < 20; i++)
       {
           num = ranNum.nextInt(10);
           list.add(num);
       }
       
       Collections.shuffle(list);
       for (int i = 0; i<20; i++)
       {
           list.get(num);
       }
       
       return num;
   }
```

```
int rand1 = numberGenerator();
int rand2 = numberGenerator();
int sum = rand1 + rand2;
String sumCompare = String.valueOf(sum);
```

And I have this code to present the question:

```
while (problem.getSum() < 10)
            {
                problem.setText("What is " + problem.getRand1() + " + " + problem.getRand2()
                + " ?");
                problem.setAnswer(problem.getSumCompare());
                presentQuestion(problem);
            }
```

Let's say the random numbers it spits out is 2 and 3. It will ask me, "What is 2+3?" And then I'll answer it correctly, and it asks me another question, but it will again ask me "What is 2+3?" I need the code to ask me a different addition question, and not use the same numbers over and over again. I apologize in advance if I am missing information and please let me know if more needs to be known, I tried to include as much as I could!

Comment: so.... just do what you ask? "It will ask me, "What is 2+3?" And then I'll answer it correctly, and it asks me another question", so generate new numbers on an accepted answer. If you got this far, you've got this: just generate new numbers.

Comment: You've made this overly complicated.  Your method `numberGenerator()` is not needed, and it certainly doesn't need an `ArrayList` and shuffling, the `Random` class hands you random numbers on demand.  Speaking of which, you also should ***not*** be creating a new `Random` object every time you need a new value.  Create one instance of `Random` in your program, then keep re-using it.

Comment: I'm with @pjs.  Your code is much more complex than necessary.

Comment: @pjs unfortunately the number generator method is a part of a requirement for my assignment, but thank you for pointing out my code overcomplicating things... I overcomplicate programming in my head so it looks like my code reflects that, apologies...

Comment: @Gill Is it a project requirement to have a method named `numberGenerator()`?  I ask because based on the logic you've described, all it seems necessary for you to do is return the value obtained from `nextInt()`, which hardly seems worth wrapping in a method given that the `Random` instance should be static and created in your `main`.

Comment: What does inheritance have to do with anything here?

Comment: @pjs Yeah, my professor stressed that we should have a numberGenerator() method in a super class to be used for 3 sub classes

Comment: @BasilBourque it's just a requirement for the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in comments, (a) Your question is not clear, and (b) You are overthinking the problem, apparently. Your list and shuffling seems irrelevant to me, unless I have misunderstood your intentions.

Do a while loop, testing for a condition as to whether to continue or not.

On each loop, generate your pair of numbers. Ask the user for their answer. Compare to your own calculated sum. [Lather, rinse, repeat.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lather,_rinse,_repeat)

```java
int min = 7;
int max = 42;
try ( Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in ) )
{
    boolean go = true;
    while ( go )
    {
        int x = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( min , max );
        int y = ThreadLocalRandom.current().nextInt( min , max );
        int z = ( x + y );

        System.out.println( x + " + " + y + " = ? " );
        int input = scanner.nextInt();

        if ( input == z )
        {
            System.out.println( "Yep." );
        } else
        {
            System.out.println( "Nope. Sum = " + z );
        }

        System.out.println( "Do it again? ( true or false ) " );
        go = scanner.nextBoolean();
    }
}
```

When run.

```
30 + 31 = ? 
44
Nope. Sum = 61
Do it again? ( true or false ) 
true
31 + 37 = ? 
68
Yep.
Do it again? ( true or false ) 
true
10 + 7 = ? 
17
Yep.
Do it again? ( true or false ) 
false
```